# array parameter when overriden in method doesn't change outside of it

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that has a parameter with string array. When in function I override it with another array it does not change outside of it (if I understand correctly arrays are passed by reference).

I have a method that looks like this:

```
    static void Method(string word, string[] tab)
    {
        string [] tab1;
        [..] 

        tab = tab1; // tab changes to tab1
    }

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string[]  tab = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
         Method("443", tab);
         //and here tab does not change like I though it would.
     }
```

Comment: Make `tab` a `ref`.

Comment: You don't "override" it, you "reassign" it. Terminology is important. Question is: do you really need to reassign the array? Can't you modify the original, or even better, return a new array?

Comment: Explanation: the array is passed, by value, as a reference. Not 'by reference'. With Toth's answer below you pass the reference by reference. Exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better design would be:

```
static string[] Method(string word, string[] tab)
{
    string [] tab1;
    [..] 

    return tab1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string[] tab = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
     tab = Method("443", tab);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it by reference:

```
static void Method(string word, ref string[] tab)
{
    string [] tab1;
    [..] 

    tab = tab1; // tab changes to tab1
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string[]  tab = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
     Method("443", ref tab);
     //and here tab does not change like I though it would.
 }
```

Explanation: Yes the arrays are reference objects but passed this reference by value default, so you can change its content to the outter scope. But the parameter (tab) only holds the copy of this reference because this reference passed by value. If you want to modify directly the passed parameter's reference to refer to a different object you need to use the `ref` keyword.

If you want to avoid `ref` keyword you need to return the new array, and use this in the `Main` method.

```
static string[] Method(string word, string[] tab)
{
    string [] tab1;
    [..] 

    return tab1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string[]  tab = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
     tab = Method("443", 
}
```

Comment: No, they don't _need_ to, it is one of the options. Another, cleaner option would be to return a new array instead.

Comment: There is a distinction with reference objects passed by value (you can change object's *contents* visible to the caller) and passed as ref parameters (you can change it to refer to a *different object* visible to the caller). So no, arrays are not passed by reference, but being reference objects, you can change the content.